# Insert form data from nodejs to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const express = require("express");
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.engine(".hbs", handlebars({ defaultLayout: "main", extname: ".hbs" }));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
"mongodb://usresa:passcode@mongodb-rukshi-shard-00-00.nerbj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,mongodb-rukshi-shard-00-01.nerbj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,mongodb-rukshi-shard-00-02.nerbj.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/db_name?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-dxrzem-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority",
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);
const nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
naquantityme: String,
description: String,
});
const User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("login", { layout: "loginlayout" });
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
res.render("dashboard", { layout: "main" });
});

app.use("/AddProduct", (req, res) => {
res.render("AddProduct", { layout: "main" });
});

app.post("/addproductform", (req, res) => {
var myData = new User(req.body);
myData
.save()
.then((item) => {
res.send("Product saved to database");
})
.catch((err) => {`enter code here`
res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
});`enter code here
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});



///// Front End
 <form id="form_validation" method="post" action="/addproductform">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" name="name"
                                        required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"
                                        required>
                                </div>
                                {{!-- <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="radio inlineblock m-r-20">
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" class="with-gap" value="option1">
                                        <label for="male">Male</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="radio inlineblock">
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" class="with-gap" value="option2"
                                            checked="">
                                        <label for="Female">Female</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div> --}}
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Description"
                                        class="form-control no-resize" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                                {{!-- <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox">I have read and accept the terms</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div> --}}
                                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary waves-effect" id="submitDetails"
                                    name="submitDetails" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                            </form>
```

This is appjs code. Rest I have AddProduct in views folder.
The default setting for accesing the view is from views folder.
This addproduct form is not submitting the datat to database.
How do we change the route of different views
This addproduct form is not submitting the datat to database.
This addproduct form is not submitting the datat to database.
This addproduct form is not submitting the datat to database.

Comment: this is your backend and where is frontend?

Comment: added front end part as well